# copy several lines from one file to another

Tags: grep, text-processing

I would like to use grep in order to copy from one file to another all lines that are between lines `/protein_id=` untill the end of the protein sequence shown. For example, from this input:

```
 CDS             448..1269
                 /gene="nptII"
                 /note="neomycin phosphotransferase II"
                 /codon_start=1
                 /product="kanamycin resistance protein"
                 /protein_id="AAQ05967.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:33320494"
                 /translation="MAITLSATSLPISARIRAGSPAAWVERLFGYDWAQQTIGCSDAA
                 VFRLSAQGRPVLFVKTDLSGALNELQDEAARLSWLATTGVPCAAVLDVVTEAGRDWLL
                 LGEVPGQDLLSSHLAPAEKVSIMADAMRRLHTLDPATCPFDHQAKHRIERARTRMEAG
                 LVDQDDLDEEHQGLAPAELFARLKARMPDGEDLVVTHGDACLPNIMVENGRFSGFIDC
                 GRLGVADRYQDIALATRDIAEELGGEWADRFLVLYGIAAPDSQRIAFYRLLDEFF"
  regulatory      1443..2148
```

I would want this output:

```
                 /protein_id="AAQ05967.1"
                 /db_xref="GI:33320494"
                 /translation="MAITLSATSLPISARIRAGSPAAWVERLFGYDWAQQTIGCSDAA
                 VFRLSAQGRPVLFVKTDLSGALNELQDEAARLSWLATTGVPCAAVLDVVTEAGRDWLL
                 LGEVPGQDLLSSHLAPAEKVSIMADAMRRLHTLDPATCPFDHQAKHRIERARTRMEAG
                 LVDQDDLDEEHQGLAPAELFARLKARMPDGEDLVVTHGDACLPNIMVENGRFSGFIDC
                 GRLGVADRYQDIALATRDIAEELGGEWADRFLVLYGIAAPDSQRIAFYRLLDEFF"
```

Note that the input could vary in that the line starting with `regulatory` could be replaced with something else. What is unchanging is that the sequence is given in capital letters and ends with a `"`. Is it possible with grep?

Comment: [Karel's answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/601090/216503) is perfect if you insist on `grep`..although should mention an alternate easier `sed` way: `sed '/db_xref/,/regulatory_class/!d' file.txt`

Comment: No it isn't. The question has been changed, so I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 4):

`pcregrep` is a grep utility that uses perl 5 compatible regexes. Perl-style regexps have many useful features that the standard POSIX ones don't. This is basically the same as grep but with a different regexp syntax.

```
sudo apt-get install pcregrep  
pcregrep -M .*'/protein_id=.*(\n|.)*\"' path/to/input-file
```

`/protein_id` is the start search term and `"` is the end search term.

Here is a generalized example of a command for doing a multiline search for all lines that are between a start search term and an end search term:

```
pcregrep -M .*'START-SEARCH-TERM.*(\n|.)*END-SEARCH-TERM' path/to/SOURCE-FILE >> path/to/DESTINATION-FILE
```

where:

- SOURCE-FILE is the file containing your data
- DESTINATION-FILE is the file where the results will be copied
- START-SEARCH-TERM is the start search term
- END-SEARCH-TERM is the end search term
- `-M, --multiline` Allow patterns to match more than one line.

Comment: Doesn't `grep -P` support PCRE?

Comment: @muru yes, but it won't match across newlines. Grep only ever reads a single line. You can seek with `-A` and `-B` but not match patterns across multiple lines.

Comment: Thanks, it did not work for 100% in the second file I am still getting unnecessary informations:

Answer (score 3):

No, `grep` can't match across multiple lines. You could do it with `pcregrep` as shown by @karel, but not pure `grep`. Instead, since you know that the protein sequences will always be in UPPER CASE and will end with `"`, you could match that:

1. `sed`

   ```
   sed -n '/\/protein_id=/,/^\s*[[:upper:]]\+"\s*$/{p}' two_seq.txt
   ```

   The `sed` pattern `/foo/,/bar/{p}` means "print all lines between `foo` and `bar`.  The `-n` suppresses normal output so only the lines requested are printed. Note that the `/` of `/protein_id=` needs to be escaped (`\/`) because the `/` is part of the match operator. The second pattern is a bit more complex, it looks for 0 or more spaces at the beginning of the line (`^\s*`), then one or more upper case letters followed by a double quote (`[[:upper:]]"`) and then 0 or more whitespace characters until the end of the line (`\s*$`).
2. Perl

   ```
   perl -ne 'print if m#/protein_id=# ... m#[A-Z]+"\s*$#' file.flat
   ```

   The same idea here, the `...` operator specifies a range and lines between the two patterns are printed.
3. `awk`

   ```
   awk '/\/protein_id=/{a=1}; a==1{print} /^\s*[[:upper:]]+"\s*$/{a=0}' file.flat
   ```

   Here, we're setting the variable `a` to `1` if the line matches the first pattern and to `0` if it matches the last. Then, we tell `awk` to print if `a` is `1`. Since the `print` is called before `a` is set to `0` for the second pattern, this will include the line containing the second pattern  as well.

Comment: Thanks, I tried all but its not working 100%, in the out file I still have unnecessary lines:
/regulatory_class="terminator"
/db_xref="GI:33320495"
/translation="MREAVIAEVSTQLSEVVGVIERHLEPTLLAVHLYGSAVDGGLKP
HSDIDLLVTVTVRLDETTRRALINDLLETSASPGESEILRAVEVTIVVHDDIIPWRYP
AKRELQFGEWQRNDILAGIFEPATIDIDLAILLTKAREHSVALVGPAAEELFDPVPEQ
DLFEALNETLTLWNSPPDWAGDERNVVLTLSRIWYSAVTGKIAPKDVAADWAMERLPA
QYQPVILEARQAYLGQEDRLASRADQLEEFVHYVKGEITKVVGK"
10706..11324
/note="right border" 
Why is that, is something missing in the sed perl or awk command lines?

Comment: @UrszulaUciechowska that's strange. What is your input file? It looks like some kind of flat file format, could you give me a link to the original file so I can test it? You probably have extra characters between the matching patterns.

Comment: yes, I have some extra lines. I was thinking that it should work. I put the txt file here https://www.sendspace.com/file/2o72m3 its two_seq.txt.

Comment: @UrszulaUciechowska ah, yes. That's because the input file has multiple occurrences of `/db_xref=` and `/regulatory_class=` and I am guessing you only want the ones describing the CDS. It might be easier if you could join me in [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22269/room-for-terdon-and-ursula) so you can explain your requirements ore precisely. You can then come and edit your question to clarify.